# Operator @ is not exist error

Tags: c#, postgresql

I try to update rows, but it's problem, becouse compiler says "Operator is not exist @ character varying".
Anybody knows why?

```
p.sql = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE users SET us_middlename = @us_middlename, us_country_home = @us_country_home, us_city_home = @us_city_home,  us_type = @us_type, us_org_id = @us_org_id, us_institution_id = @us_institution_id WHERE us_id ='" + id1 + "';", npgSqlConnection);

p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@us_middlename", user_par.us_middlename); //have character varying value
                            p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@us_country_home", user_par.us_country_home); //have int value
                            p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@us_city_home", user_par.us_city_home); //have int value
p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@us_type", user_par.us_type);//have int value
 p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@us_org_id", user_par.us_org_id);//have int value
                            p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@us_institution_id", user_par.us_institution_id);//have int value
count = p.sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for Npgsql you need to use `:` symbols for your parameter names in the query:

```
p.sql = new NpgsqlCommand(
   "UPDATE users " +
   "SET " +
      "us_middlename = :us_middlename, " +
      "us_country_home = :us_country_home, " +
      "us_city_home = :us_city_home, " +
      "us_type = :us_type, " +
      "us_org_id = :us_org_id, " +
      "us_institution_id = :us_institution_id " +
   "WHERE us_id ='" + id1 + "';",
   npgSqlConnection
);
```

For the parameters, you don't have to add the `:` (I've seen examples both with them and without them, so try both if you can.)

```
p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("us_middlename", user_par.us_middlename); //have character varying value
p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("us_country_home", user_par.us_country_home); //have int value
p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("us_city_home", user_par.us_city_home); //have int value
p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("us_type", user_par.us_type);//have int value
p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("us_org_id", user_par.us_org_id);//have int value
p.npgSqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("us_institution_id", user_par.us_institution_id);//have int value
count = p.sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should also use a parameter for `id1`, but that is a different issue.

Comment: "id1" is filled always in by "id1 = record1.FM("30");" . And your suggestion
has syntax error "near ',' "...

Comment: @Svetlana ok I've updated with hopefully a better answer. I'm unable to test it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add semicolon  after `id1` also I suggest u to pass the `id1` through parameter

```
p.sql = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE users SET us_middlename = @us_middlename, us_country_home = @us_country_home, us_city_home = @us_city_home,  us_type = @us_type, us_org_id = @us_org_id, us_institution_id = @us_institution_id WHERE us_id ='" + id1 +"'", npgSqlConnection); //Removed ;
```